# Run JS on new page with Puppeteer

Tags: chromium, puppeteer

I thought I have pretty simple task for such a tool, but I get stuck. I need just click on a link, and after that click on another link on opened page.

```
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        devtools: true
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const uri = 'https://localhost/news';
    await page.goto(uri, {waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 30000});

    //save target of original page to know that this was the opener:
    const pageTarget = page.target();

    //execute click on first tab that triggers opening of new page
    await page.click('.menu a');
    //check that the first page opened this new page:
    const newTarget = await browser.waitForTarget(target => target.opener() === pageTarget);
    //get the new page object:
    const newPage = await newTarget.page();
    await page.waitFor(funcs.randd(5000, 8000));
    await newPage.click('.main-news a');
    await page.waitForNavigation();
});
```

This code just clicks only first time on menu, but nothing happened at new page.

I use Linux Mint, nodejs 9.11.2.

Comment: This looks like a nice code, what's inside `funcs.randd`? Can you share the code? Can you wait for 60 seconds and then share the error log? Seems it's failing on waitingForTarget?

Comment: Second this, code works fine for me on node 9.11.2 *Windows 7x64 though*. Any peculiar error messages in console maybe?

Comment: Thanks, you were right. I got an error at console after about 20 seconds after first click: `(node:19897) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Node is either not visible or not an HTMLElement.` And I forgot to mention the page is opened in new tab after first click. So may the link is not visible, because it tried to find it one previous tab?
funcs.randd is just returns random number from passed range.